# JBoss 5 scheduling background tasks. Executed one after another which breaks the schedule

Tags: java, jboss5.x, scheduled-tasks

For example, I have two tasks:

```
  <mbean code="org.jboss.varia.scheduler.Scheduler" name=":service=Scheduler">
    <attribute name="StartAtStartup">true</attribute>
    <attribute name="SchedulableClass">Scheduler1</attribute>
    <attribute name="InitialStartDate">NOW</attribute>
    <attribute name="SchedulePeriod">60</attribute>
    <attribute name="InitialRepetitions">-1</attribute>
    <attribute name="FixedRate">false</attribute>
  </mbean>

  <mbean code="org.jboss.varia.scheduler.Scheduler" name=":service=Scheduler2">
    <attribute name="StartAtStartup">true</attribute>
    <attribute name="SchedulableClass">Scheduler2</attribute>
    <attribute name="InitialStartDate">NOW</attribute>
    <attribute name="SchedulePeriod">3600</attribute>
    <attribute name="InitialRepetitions">-1</attribute>
    <attribute name="FixedRate">false</attribute>
  </mbean>
```

I.e. first is scheduled every minute, the second every hour.

The problem is, that if execution of the second task takes, say 5 minutes, then the first one is not executed during this time and it waits till the second one is done.

Is there a way to have them working in parallel? Or I should move to Quartz or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<attribute name="TimerName">jboss:service=TimerNew</attribute>
```

It will start the schedule in parralel.

Comment: So just add this node to both? Or something like jboss:service=TimerNew1, jboss:service=TimerNew2 etc. ?

Comment: Use with combinition Like  <depends>user:service=MyTimer,name=Task1</depends>
<attribute name="TimerName">user:service=MyTimer,name=Task1</attribute>         and <depends>user:service=MyTimer,name=Task2</depends>

<attribute name="TimerName">user:service=MyTimer,name=Task2</attribute>         for refrence [Concurrent scheduler tasks](https://community.jboss.org/message/588965)